# How to append multi json results used for autocomplete in one text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

I am tyring to append different autocomplete list results  in one text box. It is easy to give different text box for different autocomplete results.

**html :**

```
<input id="university" name="university" type="text" />
<input id="university1" name="university1" type="text" />
```

**js :**

```
var jsonsample = [{"value":"Stanford University","name":"Stanford University"},{"value":"Santa Clara University", "name":"Santa Clara University"}]
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/varun30/zerk0pz5/2/)</kbd>

Is it possible to have both autocomplete list in one text box on a trigger of any key?

Answer (score 0):

You can add values to a JSON like this

```
jsonsample.push(
    {value: "Test University", name: "Test University Name"}
);
```

I imagine you will have to $.each all of your other objects for this to work.

```
$.each(json2, function(i, item) {
    jsonsample.push(
        {value: item.value, name: item.name}
    );
});
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement multiple values in one text box while having different data sources .Is it possible ?It s possible to implement multiple values with same source by comma separator but can we have different sources?